# Chrome Webdriver loses user credentials when in headless mode

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

Im trying to set up headless chrome for CI selenium testing.
Our webservice is using AD for authorisation. For whatever reason when chromedriver is set to headless mode it gets "Access is Denied - 401.2" when trying to acces any of our service's pages. But as soon as I launch it normally (with window as opposed to headless), everything works fine.

Here is how I set up webdriver:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions{
    BinaryLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application/chrome.exe"
};
chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() { "headless", "disable-gpu", "no-sandbox" });
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(mainPageURL);
```

After trying to run any tests with this setup (and getting 401.2) IIS logs something like this:

```
2017-06-23 11:25:12 ::1 GET / - 39731 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+HeadlessChrome...
```

But as soon as I remove "headless" from arguments, logs look like this:

```
2017-06-23 11:26:15 ::1 GET / - 39731 [USER_LOGIN] ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome...
```

With my login in place of [USER_LOGIN].

So it would seem that user login gets lost while in "headless" mode.
So far I'v tied impersiation, runing with "profile-directory=Default" argument, and runing older version of chrome (I'm currently on Canary 61.0.3138.0 64bit - newest available).

Comment: What exactly does the "mainPageURL" consist of?

Answer (score 0):

Just going out on a limb, but what does https://user:pass@test.com/test do?  That's why I asked what does mainPageURL consist of.

**UPDATE:**

```
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(**username**, **password**));
```

Maybe?

Comment: I'v tried passing username and password with URL like you suggested - dose nothing sadly. MainUrl is just a landing page of our service, something like http://service-test.loc